# ¿Cómo quitar un guión del final de un resultado de un bucle?

Tags: javascript, bucles

Muy buenas, sé que la pregunta es muy chorra pero me tiene un poco picado.

Tengo este código que básicamente imprime los múltiples de 10 hasta obtener un resultado inferior o igual a 1500, hasta aquí todo guay:

```
<!-- 7. Mostrar els múltiples de 10 fins al valor 1500.
        Ha d'aparèixer en pantalla 10-20-30 etc.. -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Pràctica 9</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script>
            function inici() {
                var resultat = document.getElementById("resultat");

                // Declaramos el vector "serie" y demás variables.
                var serie = [];
                var resul = 0;
                var num = 10;
                var i = 1;
                var res = "";

                var titol = "<h1>Múltiples de 10:</h1>";
                    resultat.innerHTML = titol;

                // Comprobar condiciones e imprimir los resultados.
                while (resul < 1500) {
                    resul += num * 1;
                    i ++;
                    resultat.innerHTML += resul + "-";
                }
            }       

            window.onload = inici;

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="resultat"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

La cosas es que a la hora de ejecutar el programa en el navegador, la serie acaba en "-".

Es decir, quiero que cada número se separe por guión pero no que haya un guión al final, no sé si me explico.

PD: Adjunto captura.

Gracias de antemano.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

También puedes hacer:

```
// Comprobar condiciones e imprimir los resultados
while (resul < 1500 - num) {
  resul += num;
  resultat.innerHTML += resul + "-";
}
resultat.innerHTML += resul + num;
```

Es decir, muestras todos los múltiplos del número hasta 1500-num (es decir, uno menos). A todos esos les imprimes con el símbolo -.

Después, fuera del bucle añades el último múltiplo, sin el -.

Por otra parte hay ciertas variables que no usas, puedes quitarlas.

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos, pero marco tu respuesta como mejor respuesta porqué creo que a algún principiante más le puede ayudar a entender la lógica de cómo funcionan los bucles.

Answer (score 1):

Lo puedes hacer muy facil con un `slice()`:

```js
var cadena="999-1000-";

console.log(cadena.slice(0,-1));
```

Luego analizando el código veo que tienes una variable `res`, empleala para guardar la cadena acumulada en lugar de agregar los números con `innerHTML` dentro del bucle, de ese modo podrás quitar el guion al final:

```js
function inici() {
                var resultat = document.getElementById("resultat");

                // Declaramos el vector "serie" y demás variables.
                var serie = [];
                var resul = 0;
                var num = 10;
                var i = 1;
                var res = "<h1>Múltiples de 10:</h1>";

                // Comprobar condiciones e imprimir los resultados.
                while (resul < 1500) {
                    resul += num * 1;
                    i ++;
                    res+=resul+'-';
                }
                resultat.innerHTML = res.slice(0,-1);
            }       

            window.onload = inici;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Pràctica 9</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="resultat"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Espero te sea de utilidad, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Otra forma de hacerlo es verificar si la iteración es la última, de esa manera no concatenas el '-'. Pdta. Este código se puede mejorar mucho.

```
while (resul < 1500) { 
     resul += num * 1;
     i ++;

     if( resul == 1500 ) { // Solo se ejecuta en la última iteración
          resultat.innerHTML += resul;
     }
     else {
          resultat.innerHTML += resul + "-";
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo aplicando el operador `?:`  me supongo que en `resul += num * 1` en vez de **1** es **i**

Ejemplo:

```
while (resul < 1500) {
      resul += num * 1;
      i ++;
      resultat.innerHTML+=((resultat.innerHTML)?'-':'')+resul;
}
```